# Is updating a part of a value possible in Redis?

Tags: redis, jedis

I have to use Redis and Jedis in a project, in order to access quickly to some data from generated keys. The value stored will be some complex Java objects.

Is it possible to update only a part of this value, without getting it before ?

For exemple, if I serialize an object of a classe like that

```
public class MyObject {

    private MySubObject1 myObj1;
    private MySubObject2 myObj2;
    private MySubObject3 myObj3;

}
```

If MyObject is associated with a key in Redis, can I from that key only update the myObj2 field ? Or have I to get the value first, update the field and put it again in Redis ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to update like this. You can use a hash instead of flat key value store.

Here is the snippet

```
    hset("MyObject","myObj1",(serialized value of myobj1))
hset("MyObject","myObj2",(serialized value of myobj2)) ...

If you want to change myObj2 alone 

do hset("MyObject","myObj2",(new value))
```